# Angular JS repeat quantity inside containers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/njt1982/1m14yrrs/

I have an example dataset like this:

```
[
    { quantity: 2, type: { name: 'alpha', id: 1 }},
    { quantity: 4, type: { name: 'beta',  id: 2 }},
    { quantity: 1, type: { name: 'delta', id: 3 }}
]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<div class="items">
    <i class="item-type-1" />
    <i class="item-type-1" />
    <i class="item-type-2" />
    <i class="item-type-2" />
    <i class="item-type-2" />
    <i class="item-type-2" />
    <i class="item-type-3" />
</div>
```

However I cannot figure out how to make Angular do a loop over my items and then "loop" over the quantity range, without getting loads of wrappers. In my fiddle, I have one wrapper around each "type", which I dont want. Can I iterate over the top level array, without creating items?

From what I've searched for on here, it looks like I might need `ng-repeat-start` ?

## UPDATE

I have accepted Sulthan's answer, below, and produced this updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njt1982/b68a8577/2/

(using a scope-level function to generate a collection of items for Angular to repeat over).

Comment: `ng-repeat-start` won't help you, you do need two nested `ng-repeat`. You can hide that behing a custom directive though.

Comment: You'd be better off creating a custom directive. Don't always rely on the ng-* components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat-start` won't help you here at all. What you actually want is a nested `ng-repeat`.

You want to first iterate over `items` and then for every item iterate `quantity` times. However, since `ng-repeat` works only on tags, you won't be able to use two nested ng-repeats to generate your flat structure. You will have to add some nesting (which can be hidden by css, of course). Also have in mind that to iterate `n` times using `ng-repeat`, you have to actually generate the array `[0, 1, 2, 3 .... n - 1]`.

If you don't want additional tags, your only (or I believe it's the only) solution is preprocessing. Just add a function to your controller that that will take your array of items as a parameter, iterate over it and multiply the items. Then your html will be just

```
<i ng-repeat="item in getModifiedItems(items)" ng-class="...">
```

A simple implementation being:

```
$scope.getModifiedItems = function (items) {
    var newItems = [];

    var i, j;
    var item;

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item = items[i];

        for (j = 0; j < item.quantity; j++) {
            newItems.push(angular.copy(item));
        }
    }        

    return newItems;
}
```

Comment: Ah so, using my jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/njt1982/1m14yrrs/, I would need a scope method which aggregates all my types and expands out the quantity for each one to generate an array of items I can loop over using ng-repeat?

Comment: @Nick Yes. It's actually pretty common. Or just add nesting for every item.

Comment: Thanks - that works well, See this updates fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njt1982/b68a8577/2/